# Getting the error "Format not a string literal and no format arguments"

Tags: xcode, nsstring, string-formatting

I looked on here and didnt see my same situation. Anyone willing to help, thanks.

I have a Grouped Table that displays my football teams games this upcoming season. Home Games and Away Games.

```
     NSString *message = [[NSString alloc] initWithFormat:rowValue];
Error Message: Format not a string literal and no format arguments
```

Not really even sure what this comes from?

I used a tutorial I found online. Copied and pasted the whole thing. I only changed the values I need for my personal table. This is the only error I get? Any help??

Edit: If I need to supply more code or anything, please, let me know!

Thank you!!

-- Anthony Lombardi

Comment: What type of object/variable is "rowValue"?

Answer (score 0):

Not quite sure what you mean. I'll input a bigger block of code, that might help.

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView
didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
NSArray *listData =[self.tableContents objectForKey:
                    [self.sortedKeys objectAtIndex:[indexPath section]]];
NSUInteger row = [indexPath row];
NSString *rowValue = [listData objectAtIndex:row];

NSString *message = [[NSString alloc] initWithFormat:rowValue];

UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc]
                      initWithTitle:@"You Better Be There Or Be Watching It!"
                      message:message delegate:nil
                      cancelButtonTitle:@"Go Knights!"
                      otherButtonTitles:nil];
[alert show];
[alert release];
[message release];
[tableView deselectRowAtIndexPath:indexPath animated:YES];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Somewhat old question, and the original asker is likely long gone... but for history and future readers - here's what's going on.

The problem is because you're creating `message` with a printf style format string - `initWithFormat` expects to have a format string with % characters indicating the substitutions - e.g. %f for a float, %d for an integer etc...

Instead of a static format string (a string literal, defined in your code directly) you've passed in a dynamic string.  The compiler is confused, because you haven't passed any arguments.  If your dynamic string contained % substitutions, the gates of hell would break loose, or at the very best you're apps going to crash.

Since it makes no sense to have a format string with no arguments, it raises the error.

To fix it you can replace the `rowValue` and `message` lines with:

```
NSString *rowValue = [listData objectAtIndex:row];
NSString *message = rowValue;
```

Or more concisely:

```
NSString *message = [listData objectAtIndex:row];
```

Or using new objective-c literals syntax and subscripting:

```
NSString *message = listData[row];
```